# Excel VBA Worksheet Change Event Causes Message Box to Appear Multiple Times

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

The below code checks to ensure a certain cell has a value before changing the color back to the sheet's original color. By changing the color from yellow to the sheet's original color, the user is able to print. The issue is that once a value is entered, the message box keeps appearing when anything else on the form is changed. Should the message box be placed outside of the worksheet change event? I am new to programming so any help is appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Anthem"
  If Range("G50").Value <> "" Then
    MsgBox "You may now print"
    Range("G50").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
  End If
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Anthem", AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Anthony

Comment: Your code tells Excel to check for any changes on the sheet, then unprotect the sheet, and if G50 has something, pop up a message and change the background colour. What do you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, stop protecting/unprotecting the worksheet every time something changes. Put this code in the worksheet's private code sheet along with the Worksheet_Change and run it once.

```
private sub protectOnce()
    me.Unprotect Password:="Anthem"
    me.Protect Password:="Anthem", AllowFormattingRows:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
end sub
```

Now you can do anything you want to the worksheet with VBA without having to unprotect it. If you have protect/unprotect anywhere else, get rid of it now; it isn't needed.

Now, on to your actual question. Just restrict the message box action to whenever there is a change in Range("G50"), not when something unrelated changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    if not intersect(Range("G50"), target) is nothing then
        If Range("G50").Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox "You may now print"
            Range("G50").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
        end if
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this is a late comment, but I get a debug error because the worksheet is protected, and the code can't access cell G50. I put the protect and unprotect method in the worksheet code, but it doesn't seem to allow the worksheet change method to make changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this. It will only trigger if G50 is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Anthem"
    If Target.Address = Target.Worksheet.Range("G50").Address Then
        If Range("G50") <> vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "You may now print"
            Range("G50").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
        End If
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Anthem", AllowFormattingRows:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What if several cells get pasted in and G50 is one of them?

Comment: For what  I can understand, G50 is a control cell that you change to print... I don't think they would paste there. But if they do, it will promp the macro once and change the background colour. the other answers here would behave the same.

Comment: No, if G50 is only one of the cells that gets pasted then the string address will not be `"$G$50"` it will be all of the cells that received the paste. Will this work for the op's specific problem? I don't know, it might. I just wanted to point out the small potential flaw.

Answer (score 0):

disable events in your code

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
application.enableevents=false    
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Anthem"
      If Range("G50").Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "You may now print"
        Range("G50").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
      End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Anthem", AllowFormattingRows:=True
application.enableevents=true
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think this is a case of the Worksheet_Change running on top of itself since a color change does not trigger the event. I believe that it is when other cells get changed while G50 is not blank.

Comment: Also, NEVER call Application.EnableEvents = False without having error handling in place to turn it back on if there's an error in your code.